# How to clean a water tank

Tags: cleaning, water, storage, plastics

I've a plastic water storage tank as such with a small lid (12"/30cm in diameter).

[image]

It has developed a thin slippery/shiny layer inside of the walls overtime and  surface of the water has the same texture.
This tank, as far as I can remember, does not have a drain near the bottom.

My question is,

1. what is that sticky film/material?
2. how to get that sticky film/material off the walls and base?
3. after (2), How to drain **all** of the water completely and easily, **without moving** the tank?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

answering the questions in order:

1. "slippery/shiny layer" sounds like a [biofilm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biofilm), and there may also be layers of precipitates (e.g. iron or manganese oxides) embedded. Some of the organisms may be innocuous, but some could be pathogenic. There is a [US EPA paper](http://www.epa.gov/ogwdw/disinfection/tcr/pdfs/whitepaper_tcr_biofilms.pdf) on the specific organisms found.
2. Chlorine-based disinfectants (basically, hypochlorite bleach) and *lots* of scrubbing should get rid of the film.
3. A sponge, perhaps on a stick should soak up any standing water after [siphoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siphon) off most of it. However, sodium hypochlorite is *safe* to ingest in drinking water **if sufficiently diluted**, i.e. [5 to 10 milliliters of 1% sodium hypochlorite solution in 20 liters of water](http://www.cdc.gov/safewater/chlorination-faq.html), so there is no problem if some is left after cleaning..

Comment: thanks for the answer. is there are way that I could get rid of the biofilm with only little scrubbing since the lid of the tank isn't large enough for me to get into and tank is large enough to not be accessible from inside easily (stupid design, if you ask me)? Any compound that just gets rid of it if put in water? BTW I havn't been to a hardware store/home depot looking for cleaning brushes for large tanks yet.

Comment: It depends on how adherent is the film... bleach alone *might* remove it; give it an hour or two to work. As for the brush, a sponge on a stick should do.

Comment: @Ejaz We use a 14% solution of sodium hypochlorite to clean this kind of *gunk* out of bilges, or even most marine growth on ship hulls. This concentration is not yet immediately dangerous but gets rid of these films without any scrubbing. Make sure you don't get any into your eyes and if you do, clean with plenty of water.

Comment: As @Ejaz suggests, be careful on skin and *clothing* (not just bleaching, but, eventually, holes) and do *not* let 14% sodium hypochlorite sit on glass, as the alkali will etch it after a while. It should be fine in a plastic carboy, but rinse well before use.

Comment: If cost is not an issue, you could use a new cotton mop that reduces the chances of scratching the surface but provide sufficient friction to work through the film to the surface of the tank. It's use would be restricted to appropriate storage and care after application. The bleach helps to ensure aseptic treatment.